# Visual Studio 2012 Prerequisites: Incorrect Function Setup Failure

Tags: visual-studio, windows-8, visual-studio-2012

When I attempt to install Visual Studio 2012 I am presented with this error:

[image]

> Visual Studio 2012 Prerequisites: Incorrect Function

How can I resolve this so I can install Visual Studio 2012?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This error[rare?] occurs when you attempt to install Visual Studio with any or all of the add-ons like Blend &/or Lightswitch, or even none.

It can be resolved by using the Visual Studio 2012 Web Installer.

Comment: Did not solve the problem for me. Trying to install Visual Studio 2012 Express, I previously had Visual C# 2010 Express installed. No add-ons.

Comment: The first attempt, all of the add-ons were checked by default.
After the crash, I tried a reinstall with no changes. It crashed.
I then modified the install. I had to check at least on add-on. I chose MFC class. The install worked.

Comment: My last comment was incorrect. When I modified the installation, it only added those new files, it did not reinstall. I finally had to install via the Web Installer, not by creating the .iso, as the original comment indicated.

Answer (score 0):

Just restarting the install worked for me.

Answer (score 0):

The ISO and the web install both failed for me.  The only thing that got it close was the Service Pack update.